# Access shared storage on Android with Qt

Tags: android, qt, file, android-external-storage

How to create folder, which could be accessed later from pc? How to access Android external storage, preferably without engaging JNI (but, better JNI than nothing).

For ex. create folder: `Android/data/com.package.name/files/myfolder`

I've already tested all of the `QStandardPaths`, and getting path from "`EXTERNAL_STORAGE`" variable in `QProcessEnvironment` (result: `"/storage/emulated/legacy/myfolder"`), creating dir with `QDir::mkpath`.

Comment: `Android/data/com.package.name/files/myfolder`. That path does not exist to begin with.

Comment: So you used mkpath() ? That should work.

Comment: Why not just mount _external storage_ on pc and use OS to access it??

Comment: '"/storage/emulated/legacy/myfolder"' is path returned from env EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

I need to make an app, creating a folder in shared (external) space, in which you can put some files from pc. mkpath will do the job, when I will acquire equivalent of the 'getExternalStorageDirectory'.